# How to get rid of decimal numbers in my html razor code

Tags: c#, razor

I'm using

```
@spaceEvent.TotalSpaceReviews.ToString("N")
```

to convert a int to a number with commas, but it shows up with a decimal and 2 numbers after the decimal. ex. 1,089.00 These values are positive integers and I don't need a decimal or numbers after the decimal. How do I remove the decimal and numbers after it?

Comment: "D" doesn't show the commas

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the number of decimal places to show after the "N", so if you don't want any, just put a `'0'` after the `N`:

```
@spaceEvent.TotalSpaceReviews.ToString("N0")
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are converting an int to a string correct? So you can add a line of code as part of the method that cuts off the last 3 characters or two if it is the same every time, like so:

str = str.substring((str.length() - 3));

Answer (score 0):

To Remove decimal numbers,you can simply use `ToString("0")` on razor code

```
@spaceEvent.TotalSpaceReviews.ToString("0")
```